# Is it better to have one "for loop" that loops through 9 arrays or make 9 "for loops" each loops over one array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have 9 arrays each have 9 elements and I need to loop all 81 elements. I know it is a very small number to effect the performance but if we multiply by a 1000 element in each array or if I had to use this method over and over which will be the better option? Or will both give the same performance ?

```
public void LoopElements1() {
    // check the [i]th element in all arrays in each loop
    // ary1.length because all arrays are same length it ok
    for (int i = 0; i < ary1.Length; i++) { 
        if ( ary1[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary2[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary3[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary4[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary5[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary6[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary7[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary8[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }

        if ( ary9[i] condition )
        { something }
        else
        { }   
    }
} // end option1
```

Or:

```
public void LoopElements2() {
    // check all elements in each array in a separate loop
    for (int i = 0; i < ary1.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary1[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary2.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary2[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary3.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary3[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary4.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary4[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary5.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary5[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary6.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary6[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary7.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary7[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary8.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary8[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ary9.Length; i++)
    { 
        if (ary9[i] condition)
        { /* something */ }
        else
        { }
    }
}// end option2
```

Comment: you must give proper idea of what content are in arrays?. If it is integer,sring, object.. and also need to specify if all array contains same type.

Comment: @KeyurNimavat, interesting point. Could you elaborate as to why these matter for the question at hand?

Comment: because if all array have same conent type then I can suggest better option for your condition.
also if you could tell conditions type like sorting or etc. then you can use collection for faster result without using for loop. so without knowing what you want it is comlex to give perfect solution.
Right now I can only say that first approh is oerfect of calling 1 loop and all conditions. but if there is better then this coding possible then I can only tell atter knowing data.

Comment: It could be indeed that knowing the type would benefit the question. For instance, I could tell you have them all implement an interface and store them all in one collection. Then you can iterate the collection and the interface implementation will take care of checking the condition and updating the data, regardless it is a Dog type or a Tank type. As long as both are IMyNeed.

Comment: You really should measure if this is a problem. If looping in itself is the problem then you will not solve the issue with a change in looping order. That said there is still benefit in using a separate loop for each array since it aids cache locality so the CPU prefetcher can load data from memory to the CPU cache. That should help you to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this one is a little tricky to answer because it lacks context. From a strictly performance-orientated viewpoint, the correct answer is *test it.* You never know what the compiler will do with your code except that it's going to be logically consistent. Implement both versions, see which one runs faster. If the resulting performance difference is negligible, I'd recommend the first version, because it reads slightly better.

***However.***

There may be a bigger underlying issue here. A common axiom of programming is "Don't Repeat Yourself". It's hard to measure, but if you've got yourself in a situation like this, where you have multiple arrays that are of the same length all being checked in the same way, then this is almost certainly a situation where you can improve the structure of your data.

If, for example, your arrays all contain the same data, then a multidimensional array is almost certainly what you want, and you can iterate over them with nested for loops, like so:

```cs
int[,] my2dArray = new int[3,5];

for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        if (ConditionCheck(my2dArray[x,y])) {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously this might not be the specific case you're actually dealing with. Not everything goes cleanly into a multidimensional array. But the general pattern here seems to be that you have a collection of collections, and you're trying to do some operation to all of them. Perhaps those inner collections can be reformatted to be something more graceful. Maybe that inner data needs to be piled into its own class or struct. It's hard to tell without knowing your exact use case, but from a general purpose standpoint, if you're in one of these situations where you've got the same code over and over again with a couple of tiny modifications each time, you should probably start thinking about how you can rearrange or reorganize things.

And remember, above all else, program for clarity *first.* Optimize later, *if* you have to, *after* you've measured your code to see where its worst performance cases are. Most of the time, clean and concise code is fast code.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases have a time complexity of `O(n)`.

However, a loop will have an overhead of incrementing the loop counter and comparing at the beginning of the loop. I recommend the one loop approach.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with VPellen: think about performance when you *need* to and focus on clarity.

If I would have to choose between the two though, I would choose the second way - but slightly adjust it, with help of [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).
I would want to, for each array, do:

```
arr.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => {/*Do Something*/} )
```

`.Where()` returns an `IEnumerable` and to get a `ForEach()` for `IEnumerable`, 
I would have to introduce an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) along the lines of:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var element in enumerable)
        {
            action(element);
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow for `.Where().ForEach()` syntax. So the result would resemble the following:

```
arr1.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr2.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr3.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr4.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr6.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr5.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr7.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr8.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
arr9.Where(x => /*Some condition*/ ).ForEach(x => { /*Do Something*/ });
```

Still pretty repetative. So I would like to see if I could somehow simplify this even further -- maybe
encapsulate the actions and/or conditions so you could then apply it for each of the arrays. 
Unfortunately it's not very clear from your question - what exactly needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

If performance are critical Ill recommend one loop with X If statements.

here is the disassembly of a basic for loop
[image]

as you can see **if you'll put X if statements you will save 8 conditions checking each iteration and 8 increments (even action that look simple as i++ is actually 3 separate operations the you CPU will have to execute)**.

you can read more about iteration and performance [in here](https://medium.com/deep-net/part-1-iteration-2f33bf5ea50f)

important to mention that if performance is not as important as readability + "clean coding", Ill just recommend to use some LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Since looping has an overhead that is indifferent to what is being done in the loop itself (increment loop counter, compare and jump eti beginning of loop); all other things being equal - go with the single loop approach